# "If the Handler is using a Looper or MessageQueue for a thread other than the main thread, then there is no issue."

Tags: android, multithreading, memory-leaks, handler, android-handler

A non-static inner `Handler` class in Android Studio shows a memory leak warning. There are lots of existing topics that cover this question and the reason for this warning.

However, I am wondering explicitly about the **underlined** sentence:

[image: MainActivity]

This is not correct, is it? When the `Handler` is associated with a non-UI `thread`, but it has a reference to an Activity, I am still leaking the activity.

Comment: Regardless of what thread an inner class captures the enclosing class, and can't be instantiated without an instance of the outer class.  The only reason for the underlined text maybe that with a handler threads looper can be quit, meaning that it might not be a permanent memory leak and be up for garbage collection afterwards, where as the main looper never quits for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: @MarkKeen Very good point, thank you.

Comment: @MarkKeen If the Handler is a non-static inner class of the Thread class itself, there should be no memory leak, right?

Comment: This depends, is the `Thread` a top level class itself? If the lifetime of the `Handler` matches the `Thread` then no. Just be careful about the scope of the `Handler` reference - strong references to the `Handler` will keep the `Thread` from garbage collection. Again this depends on the lifetime of the objects holding the reference ..

Comment: @MarkKeen If the `Thread` is a top-level class and I never save the `Handler` in a long-living variable, could the `Handler` ever outlive the enclosing `Thread` class?

Comment: If both the `Thread` and `Handler` are not reachable by any other strong references, then no, you're fine.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!